# Android Studio Action Bar wont leave

Tags: android, android-studio

A white bar covering some of the commands in android studio will not disappear, The only way to make it go away is turn off the application it self, but when I turn it back on it comes back, How do I get rid of the bar while still in studio?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, these kind of issues are normally (Any **ghost dialog**) solved  by **rebooting** my computer..